# insert a struct into a vector as binary data for network transmission

Tags: c++, vector

I am using an older network transmission function for a legacy product, which takes a `char` array and transmits it over the network. This `char` array is just data, no need for it make sense (or be null terminated). As such in the past the following occurred:

```
struct robot_info {
    int robot_number;
    int robot_type;
    ...
} // A robot info data structure for sending info.


char str[1024], *currentStrPos = str;
robot_info r_info; 
... // str has some header data added to it.
... // robot info structure is filled out
memcpy(currentStrPos, (char *)&r_info, sizeof robot_info); // Add the robot info
scanSocket.writeTo(str, currentStrPos - str); // Write to the socket.
```

We have just added a bunch of stuff to `robot_info` but i am not happy with the single length method of the above code, i would prefer a dynamiclly allocated raii type in order to be expandable, especially since there can be multiple robot_info structures. I propose the following:

```
std::vector<char> str;
... // str has some header information added to it.
... // r_info is filled out.
str.insert(str.end(), (char *)&r_info, (char *)&r_info + sizeof r_info); 
scanSocket.writeTo(str.data(), str.size());
```

[Live example.](http://ideone.com/eKDdWq)

Using the `std::vector` [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)  function (with a pointer to the start of `r_info` as the iterator) and relying on the fact that a struct here would be aligned to at least a `char` and can be operated on like this. The struct has no dynamic memory elements, and no inheritance.

*Will this have well defined behavior? Is there a better way to perform the same action?*

Comment: @kfsone If you notice the first example, its not just the struct that gets pushed into this string, other header information will be in there as well.

Comment: @baummitaugen Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @kfsone I also said `especially since there can be multiple robot_info structures`, this code is a simplification, there are for loops for a variety of structs which all get added to the string.

Comment: I'm with @kfsone. Instead of multiple calls to `str.insert()` for each structure, just make direct calls to `scanSocket.writeTo()`  with the same info.

Comment: I use that hack for the same purpose to get this *char-aligned* structure. If you can expect the total size of that structure in advance, then you won't lose performance either.

Comment: @Galik, The data is dynamic and we want to send a single packet of data (because its a scan packet) this is to satisfy newer PC side software on the other side as well as older software. So since its dyamic and we cant send in more then one packet i dont think i can send several structs. I will look into this though.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `insert` method? Put the value of `sizeof r_info` at position specified by address of `r_info`?

Comment: @Amadeus no, the implementation is that the struct `r_info` will be inserted into the `vector` as a `char` array. Look at the link for `std::vector::insert`.

Comment: @Ben And have you tried to compile it? http://ideone.com/3Or7xP

Comment: @Ben by the way, insert will not work as you are expecting. Insert takes a input interator and insert a value at there. In your case, your vector is of char, so, what it will do is, at position specified, insert the value of sizeof(r_into), if it fits in a char.

Comment: @Amadeus Wow, you are totally right, i am sorry and i have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this works, it is ultimately solving a compile time problem with a run time solution. Since `robot_info` is a defined type, a better solution would be this:

```
std::array<char, sizeof robot_info> str;
memcpy(str.data(), static_cast<char *>(&r_info), sizeof robot_info);
scanSocket.writeTo(str.data(), str.size());
```

This has the advantages:

1. Can never be over size, or undersized
2. Automatic Storage duration and stack allocation means this is potentially faster